# Variable can't be updated in this way

Tags: perl

I'm currently writing a Perl script, so i have an array @A in another array @B, but when the array @A is updated, the array @B don't take this update in consideration.

Here is my code:

```
my @A;my @B;
@B=("test",[@A]);
@A=("aaa","bbb","ccc");
print $B[1][1];
```

It work only when i change the order of lines in this way:

```
my @A;my @B;
@A=("aaa","bbb","ccc");
@B=("test",[@A]);
print $B[1][1];
```

The problem is I need to keep the order of lines as the first example?

Any help please ?

Comment: `[@a]` is the same as `do { my @anon = @a; \@anon }`. You want `\@a`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You aren't storing @A in @B, you're storing an anonymous array `[]`, originally populated by the contents of @A (i.e. empty). You can store a reference to @A, though:

```
@B = ( 'test', \@A );
```

Comment: thank you you just answered my question and resolving my problem
I'm feeling good :) 
thanks

Answer (score 6):

You're getting burnt by the difference between `[ @A ]` and `\@A`.

- `[ @A ]` means "copy the contents of `@A` into a **new** anonymous array and return a reference to that new array".
- `\@A` means "return a reference to the array `@A`".

In your first example, you copy the contents of `@A` before putting anything into it. So your new array is empty. Rewrite your first example like this and it will work.

```
my @A;
my @B;
@B = ("test", \@A);
@A = ("aaa", "bbb", "ccc");
print $B[1][1];
```